# Google MapView doesn't work after signed the app

Tags: android, android-widget

I am facing to android application signing problem. My application contains Google MapView.
When I compile the app and run on the emulator, MapView works fine. But signed the app, MapView doesn't work. I've get Google Map API. This works on the simulator.

I could sign the app once 2 months ago. Then I've upgraded the app. Now I need to sign the app again.
Actually I don't know why signed app's mapView doesn't work. How to fix it ?

Please advice.

I used following steps when sign the app:

1. Run Eclipse.
2. Select the project. Right Click -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package -> Then Filled forms. (In forms, Validity years: 200, and all passwords are same.)

Can you suggest me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes wen u sign the app u need to create another key for the MapView... This key is generated by google wen u provide the MD5 fingerprint of the key u used for signing and replace the older key u must have provided at design time in the xml...

Comment: You are the best. I am appreciate you. :)

Comment: well well well thanx dude... all the best :)

Comment: Dude, you saved my life, I was struggling to figure this out for 2 Weeks